# Can an irrational number be expressed as a sum of other irrational numbers, at least one of which is not an integral multiple of the required number?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, irrational-numbers

For example, $\pi = Ae + B\sqrt 2+ \cdots$ ($A,B,\ldots\in\mathbb R$)

(Equations like "$\pi = 3\pi - 2\pi$" are not allowed.)

Comment: What about $\pi= \sqrt 2 + (\pi-\sqrt 2)$

Comment: $\pi = (2\pi + 1) - (\pi + 1)$.  None of $\pi$, $\pi+1$, or $2\pi+1$ is a multiple of one another.

Comment: Are equations like $\pi = \pi/2 + \pi/2$ allowed?  Neither of the irrational numbers in the sum is an integral multiple of the required number, which is exactly as stated in the title.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\pi = \sqrt 2 + (\text{another irrational number}).
$$

This "other irrational number" is of course $\pi-\sqrt 2$, and so we have the question of how we know that that is irrational.  Just suppose it's rational, so then we have
$$
\pi = \sqrt 2 + \frac m n
$$
where $m,n$ are positive integers.  Then it would follow that
$$
\left( n\pi - m \right)^2 = 2n^2.
$$
That would make $\pi$ an algebraic number.  Just how to prove that $\pi$ is **not** an algebraic number takes some work, as does, for that matter, proving $\pi$ is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

hi i have one example

$$\sqrt{3}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: That's equivalent to $\sqrt{3}=\frac{2}{3} \sqrt{3}+\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{3}$